# Design Patterns - Service Layer

Tags: design-patterns, service-layer

I am currently reading a lot about Design Patterns and I have been watching various **Pluralsight** videos from their library. Now so far I have learnt the following:

1. Repository Pattern
2. Unit of Work Pattern
3. Abstract Factory Pattern
4. Reading the awesome "DI in .NET" book

Now I read lot about **Services** and **Service Layers** and wanted some advice about the best place to read up and learn about these. I presume this fits into **Domain Driven Design** and I should start there? The term "Service" just seem to be used widely within IT and it can be confusing the exact meaning.

So my questions is:

1. What is the **Service Layer**
2. Where is the best place to learn about them

Comment: You might have better results asking this question on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Arrrgh apologies I will close it down. Thanks matey!

Comment: I'm not saying you won't get a response here, but SO tends to focus on application and Programmers on theory. As asked, this question is too vague. Whole chapters of books have been written about this topic.

Comment: THat was quick! I added the post here on Programmers:

http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/178676/design-patterns-service-layer

I presume i need to close this one down as duplicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The service layer is the layer which sits between the presentation layer and the data access layer.

The presentation deals with HTTP requests and responses (in a web app) and presentation logic in general (workflow between pages, etc.), and delegates to the service layer for the business, transactional logic that the application uses.

The service layer then delegates to a data access layer to access the database.

Comment: This answers part of his question (what a service layer is), but not where to learn more.

Comment: You would typically need to choose a specific environment or framework, and then learn about the service layer in this environment: JEE, Spring, .NET, PHP?

Comment: Thanks guys appreciated. Im alittle slow replying as my left hand is in a splint and im typing with one hand!